# Please remove the "question doesn't conform to standards"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, quality-filter

My question was simple - how does IntelliJ associate jar files with scratch files, and where am I meant to put jar files for a scratch file to use?

I had to make a mess of it though to pass whatever esoteric magic SO uses to programmatically judge a "good question", see here

[IntelliJ scratch file needs a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45455758/1061426)

Normally I just delete the guff after posting the question - but this time I'm leaving it. Because if that is the standard that the system wants, then that is the standard it is getting.

Can we please get rid of this system that makes good, simple questions become unreadable messes?

Comment: A better way to go about it would perhaps have been to actually ask why your question didn't fulfil the quality requirements on meta **first**.

Comment: The Meta effect is in full bloom on the linked question even though it has long been fixed. Sigh.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a "false positive" like @Pekka says, or if it's really "fixed". It still doesn't look like a complete question to me. To be fair, though, that might be because it's outside of my domain knowledge.

Comment: @J.Steen it happens enough that it bothers me - it's terrible from a UI perspective, and this is an old site that should have UI issues done properly.

Comment: how is your question not fulfilling certain conditions a UI problem?

Comment: Note that adding garbage to a post to get it past the check is considered abusive: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354307/is-it-rude-abusive-to-include-junk-text-to-bypass-the-minimum-texts-requirements

Comment: I'm going to guess that part of the problem is that the check is used to block spam as well as poorly formatted questions, so they won't reveal details about *why* a question is being blocked.

Comment: @Will, While blocking spam is a concern, for a "normal" post, once the specific reasons a post is failing the check are stated, then people will only correct those exact problems. Effectively, they will game the issue until they just barely make it over the threshold. One of the goals of the check is to get people to *generally* improve the quality of their question, not *just* specific things. On the other hand, it would be reasonable to link to a page that describes the *general* things that are looked at, which might give users ideas about what they could improve.

Answer (score 27):

Adding garbage to your question is generally not advisable: in a tag with more traffic that will quickly earn you downvotes and closevotes.

The quality filter was likely triggered by your not capitalizing your "i"s, along with a relatively short question length. Both are notorious indicators of bad questions and together, they triggered the quality filter. (Once you made it longer, I guess that made the index fall below the threshold.)

Your case is *sort of* a false positive, but not capitalizing "i"s is a really really strong indicator of bad content and it's arguably bad English.

Just fix it - that should be enough to satisfy the quality filter. (Edit: I went ahead and did it for you before it gains any more downvotes.)

Comment: thanks - but if the "i" is the problem, then why doesn't the little robot tell me as much? I rarely capitalize any words at all, i've never really suffered for it outside of, i suppose, this SO grammar robot

Comment: @bharal Using proper grammar as part of asking a quality question is mentioned in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Comment: The filter arguably *could* mention it though. Depends on what its purpose is, I guess.

Comment: @bharal The filter is there to prompt you to improve your entire post, not just fix one thing to barely get it over the bar.

Comment: that isn't useful though - imagine if your compiler said "improve your code" and that's it... it is naturally frustrating and doesn't accomplish the issue

Comment: @bharal Stack Overflow isn't a compiler. You're writing English prose. It's up to you to make it suitable for other people to understand.

Comment: @bharal: Our goal is not to get you to ask your question. We don't want "minimally acceptable" questions. By being nebulous with you, it encourages you to put more effort into whatever you're asking.