# Can this be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

This question

[IntelliJ scratch file needs a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45455758/1061426)

is pretty clear, I think. The users who closed it - it would appear - have no interaction with IntelliJ IDEA, so they just don't understand what is being asked.

I guess there is a broader question of "if you don't understand a technical question it doesn't necessarily mean the question is unclear", but let's skip over that.

The fact that the main IntelliJ IDEA chap has already posted an answer in the comments should salve anyone's fears that this is an unclear question. I just want, for completeness, to answer my own question with what it took to get the scratch working.

*Edit*: I don't care even slightly about points on SO, nor am I bothered about downvotes or the "meta effect". I simply want to post a canonical answer to a question that I raised.

Comment: Hmmm... This isnt a great question tbh. I dont know enough of the domain to be able to determine if unclear is correct... But there is definitely a lack of details and info in the question. Linking it on meta might not end well. You just cast a massive spotlight on your Q... This may result in a bunch of downvotes more, FYI

Comment: It got 3 out of the 5 close votes from [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/90230?m=38451370#38451370) regulars. I've pinged the voters to chime in here. I expect they triggered on your [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45455758/1).

Comment: Yeah what was up with that first revision? Just checked it and..... Ugh. Pretty awful to just repeat the same two sentences over and over like that.

Comment: I read your edited question (yesterday) and didn't vote, because I'm no IntelliJ user. But I think you should add more information to you question. Maybe it is not unclear but too broad or needs a MCVE. BTW: Not one user has closed your question. It needs 5 users. Edit your question and we will see, if 5 users are voting to reopen your question. And now you learned what the meta effect is (right now you have -17).

Comment: [This got brought up on Meta yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354272/please-remove-the-question-doesnt-conform-to-standards), so it may just be coincidence that there is overlap between Meta and SOCVR regulars. @rene

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray I rather be transparent about what could have happened instead of someone calling us out.

Comment: If you have to insist [twice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354272/3001761) that everyone else is wrong, *maybe you are*.

Comment: What if you answered the question raised in the comments?

Comment: You crapped up your question, you have blamed it on the system... You have been told that adding garbage to the question was not the best thing to do.. and instead of politely asking for reopening you feel the need to add _The users who closed it - it would appear - have no interaction with IntelliJ, so they just don't understand what is being asked._ That kind of attitude will not get you far around here.

Comment: You could also add what you know doesn't work. Where did you originally put it that it failed to work properly?

Comment: As others have mentioned, the [first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45455758/1) of your question is *obviously* unclear. It looks more like an editing failure (which it is). There's a question at the top, which by itself is not that clear and arguably too broad without a bit more detail, then there's a code block that appears to have nothing to do with the question, followed by just repeating the initial sentences. You *intentionally* left your question in a state that was *obviously* unclear, without needing domain knowledge. Are you surprised that people voted to close it?

Comment: @BilltheLizard i have no idea what question you're referring to, there is no question in the comments of the original question directed at me.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I appreciate your concern for how far I will get around here. I felt it might be useful to explain why I felt the question was closed prematurely - it is a specific, niche question regarding a specific, niche feature of an IDE, and the close-vote users *appear* to not use that IDE at all. Not trying to stir people up, just expressing a reason for it being closed incorrectly.

Comment: Rather than using the closer's experience as validation for reopening, why not use the merits of the question itself? that's certain to be far more productive.

Comment: @Makyen well, yes. The close reason was "unclear", and it was closed some time after a good soul edited it. Seems to me like if the close reason is wrong, it should be reopened. I don't follow your logic that if version one is bad, regardless of the state of version 2, the question should be closed.

Comment: @KevinB I'm reasonably sure the question is legitimate and stands on its own, and I'm also reasonably sure that my just saying that wouldn't carry much water here.

Comment: That is a safe assumption to make. There appears to be many here who believe it's still unclear or should remain closed regardless, why shouldn't it be other than feelings?

Comment: @KevinB Scratch file documentation for intellij: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html I've used them in the past, but this time was using a library that wasn't associated with my project. The scratch file couldn't find the library - in java, called "jar file" - but offered no recourse. i had the feeling that I needed to tell intellij about the jar file somehow, and so, hence, my question. The "maven" i refer to is this https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html - this stuff is pretty esoteric even for java developers.

Comment: @KevinB Aside from being outraged, I'm unsure what all the close-voters wanted, a giant explanation so that a 6 year old could grasp the problem? If I did all that, the 6 year old still wouldn't be able to answer the question.

Comment: see, that's a lot more clear than the question you posted. in my opinion.

Comment: @KevinB yes, I realise that - but surely the point of me raising the question isn't to educate people on the specifics of my issue, but to find the solution? If someone doesn't know what a scratch file, or intellij, or maven is, they're not going to be able to help at all.

Comment: @bharal, Votes for closure happen anytime after the question is posted. The only vote where the time is known is the last one at actual closure, which could have been for any reason. The only thing the displayed reason indicates is that at least 2 voters voted for that reason. Unfortunately (IMO), the close system does not list all the reasons which were selected by those voting to close the question and does not require even 3 people to agree on a particular reason to display it (just 2 with none of the others matching; 3 matching when the other two match, or at least that's what I've seen).

Comment: @bharal, Questions are not reopened just because they have resolved the single issue listed in the close banner. People (should) only vote for a question to be reopened if it does not qualify for *any* of the close reasons (i.e. when it is a clear, not too broad, not opinion based, question that is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I agree this can be confusing for the OP who thinks they have resolved the single problem. There have been various proposals to improve this. I hope that one of the things the DAG team takes on is improving this situation.

Comment: @Makyen:  So what you're saying is...you still see a problem with this question?

Comment: @Makoto, No. I was only providing information as to how the system works/is supposed to work (portions of that system could use significant improvement, both for people reviewing and question authors). Frankly, in the shape it's in it's not clear to someone with limited domain knowledge that it's actually clear. In it's original state, I'm comfortable with my vote to close it (I honestly don't recall my actual close vote, but it probably was "unclear", based on the original version). If I encountered this question in the review queue, I would skip it, (continued)

Comment: @Makoto, (continued) as I don't have the domain knowledge to say it's sufficiently clear. However, I'm seriously considering voting to reopen, based on your statements (and having done a bit of research on the topic). OTOH, even just working the information that bharal has provided in comments here into the question would make it significantly clearer and show that the OP has actually done some research/attempted to resolve it themselves. Side note: It feels like bharal is going out of their way not to improve the question, which makes me less willing to expend time/effort on it.

Comment: @Makyen: I'd be incredibly discouraged too if all I see is a wall of text saying why my question is bad and why I should feel bad, too.  Vote however you like.  No improvement process by SO is going to fix your domain knowledge levels.

Comment: @Makyen please don't see it that I'm not trying to improve the question - knowing full well that people would probably be enraged, I posted one question to meta to raise my issues with the auto-robot-ai. When I checked again, someone had edited the question. If I appear to be resisting adding all sorts of exposition to the qq, it's simply because that's not what a question should be, and it detracts from the q. Questions can be solely domain-specific - although of course it's often best if answers do not assume more domain specific detail than evidenced by the question.

Comment: @Makyen as it stands, the question as-is now won't make it past the robo-ai being used. Unless SO just wants a tremendous loss of conciseness, this is the problem I tried to raise in my earlier meta.

Comment: Disclosure: I have followed your question since you posted it. I havn't DV, flag or anything. You have failed 4rth time. Your question quality is not the real issue. 1/. You faced low quality AI and Failed. ( I spend exactly 3 minute to get your question ok for the bot..)  2/. You failed your first meta post, instead of a help me improve my question, you have posted a rant on AI. 3/. You fail to edit your question with all the revelant information you had in comment

Comment: 4/. And this last meta fail, Question still have quality issue. IMO CrazyCoder do not show that your question have value! I can give you a neverending list of really bad question where top user come and drop a hint on how to solve the issue.This show the exact opposite... Finally: I understand that you faced a problem and choose to have a quick question about it, but you sacrifice the question quality. Comming to say "I have an good answer", make me ask you again where is the good question? Take a break, Delete the question. Forget it for a few days. Get it out of your system.

Comment: I didn't say the question was directed at you. There are only three comments. How hard is it to read them and clarify your question for people?

Comment: @Bill the first comment is an attempt at an answer. the second is a request for clarification for the given (commented) answer. the third is an attempt to clarify the question. there is, if i understand what you're saying, there is nothing for me to add to the question given those comments.

Comment: There is, but you obviously don't want to clarify your question.

Comment: @Bill mate, it's a community. if you think I'm missing something, you can either suggest it here, or you can edit the question and add whatever it is you see. communities don't exist where people don't contribute.

Comment: I (and others) have already suggested what you should do. You obviously don't want to do it, so discussing it further is a waste of time.

Comment: @Bill you've been arguing that there is some comment in the question under discussion that should have been used to clarify the question. My argument is that there is no such comment. I'm not sure who is agreeing with you, but you haven't suggested anything to do, aside from answer some mysterious question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why we can't have nice things...

Full disclosure: I've used IntelliJ IDEA every working day of my career, and scratch files are an amazing feature, which allows you to run arbitrary code and snippets without having to start up a new project.  I have found them limited in the case that I want to use a specific library, but I have simply worked around that; that is to say, **there is an answer for your question, and it's not one that's easy to see at first.**  It's also comforting to see that you too have an answer, and hey that's even better!

That said, while your [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45455758/1) suffered from an attempt to circumvent our very necessary quality checks, your [more current version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45455758/2) seems to be very answerable.  In fact, I can drum up an answer for it which would be useful to you and others in the future *right now*, or at least find a comparable dupe which would be ***infinitely*** more helpful than what you've got now.

As revised, this question doesn't deserve closure or deletion.

Comment: Oh, if you think that this question is alright *now*, [this micro-privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253668/help-us-identify-micro-privileges-for-top-users/259077#259077) would actually help remove the negative stigma that this question's suffered from.  I doubt anyone's actively looking at micro-privileges right now, but it couldn't hurt to mention this.

Comment: I'm not a domain expert, so I really am not able to see the potential that you do in the question. However, I'm willing to trust your judgment and consider re-opening. But, two things: (1) I still don't quite feel comfortable with the question in its current form. If you or the OP could edit it to add just a little bit more context, I would feel much better. At a minimum, using proper capitalization would help. (2) At this point, with all the negative attention it's received, it would probably be better just to ask a new question and leave this one behind for good.

Comment: @CodyGray:  Yeah, given how negatively the question's been received, it really wouldn't matter if I edited it into shape at this point.  I'd have done so earlier if I thought this could be resurrected.  A shame, really.

Comment: It's difficult for me to be too sympathetic about it. It's a fact of life that you have one chance to make a good first impression. The question made a *very bad* first impression, considering it effectively admitted to abusing the system. Hopefully the asker learned something and won't make this mistake again. Even better, we *do* allow second chances by simply reposting the question.

Comment: ...Meh.  It's more or less the symptom of something larger.  I don't deny that first impressions are important, but the punishment for getting it wrong seems a bit overly harsh.  I'll have to choose my words carefully for how it should be addressed.

Comment: Yeah, I agree the Meta effect got out of hand with this one. But it was brought up *twice*, both times in a fairly unconstructive way. If I knew of a good way to mitigate the Meta effect, I would have already proposed it. But I just cannot get behind radical solutions that have been posited in the past, like locking a question being discussed here (too disruptive to the main flow of things) or not linking it at all (almost always critical to provide context).

Comment: If only the original question, Used a little bit of those word trying to give context to his question. Just 1 or 2 more sentence would have give some keyword for future user. But in the urge of getting an answer op didn't care about quality. The only way out is to delete this question and ask a new one. It would be better if it someone could write it for OP because I feel like he won't have the energy to improve the quality of the question.