# Prevent posting of questions which contain long strings of dots as filler

Tags: feature-request, quality-improvement, quality-filter

Just like the Stack Overflow "Ask Question" box already prevents you from posting a question with a title which already exists and has a number of checks which will prevent you from posting certain types of content, I'm hoping we could implement a block against questions containing long runs of dots.

1. Some users use dots as filler to make their question long enough. (One of the blocks prevents users from posting questions which are too short.)
2. Some users apparently feel the need to post long sequences of dots in otherwise valuable answers.

Representative sample from just now;

```
<p>On Android and desktop works perfectly but on IOS at first click dont work, when click on another song and then again at first it start playing.
..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................</p>
```

[The Metasmoke spam archive contains a fair amount of these posts](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?feedback_filter=fp&reason=121). They are often not spam, but the spam filter reports these as a convenience, meaning they typically get cleaned up in a matter of minutes. But do we really need to allow this common noise in the first place?

Could we please put in a filter to prevent users from posting long runs of full stops?

Comment: Much to my chagrin, I note that the long sequence of dots in the question title gets shortened by Stack Overflow.

Comment: Or they just write: "just writing something here because the stupid system said it wasn't long enough to post or I had too much code or something!"

Comment: ...and then, after the bad question  is posted, they immediately edit out the filler.  It would be nice to think that the filler gets replaced with useful test/debug/whatever information.  Unfortunately...

Comment: The intent is to cause reasonable posters to reconsider, not to outright prevent abuse from abusive users. The latter is pointless.

Comment: I don't see repeated dots anywhere *near* as often as I see people copy-pasting the same block of text over and over. I don't see why this needs to be handled with an automatic block. We've tried that with titles, and it creates more p0rblems than it solves.

Comment: True. A lot of (new) users tend to add all sorts of garbage to get around editor restrictions not just dots. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354272/please-remove-the-question-doesnt-conform-to-standards) rather memorable post comes to mind

Comment: @CodyGray The issue seems to be that this is clogging metasmoke with a lot of false positives taking up Charcoal's time.

Comment: I don't particularly worry about the Charcoal FPs; they just triggered the idea that this is a common enough nuisance that it could probably go in there with the length checks etc.

Comment: @suraj So then fix metasmoke to address the false positives.

Answer (score 4):

And if they use "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" instead or whatever? I don't think this should be handled specifically.

Of course if you see that in a review queue, don't let it pass.

Edit: Choose rude or abusive instead of low-quality after @CodyGray comment.

Flag it for rude or abusive as it is an attempt to abuse the system, not low quality. Those posts need to be deleted.

Comment: If you can point to evidence to suggest that this is anywhere as common as the repeated dots, I'm all for extending the feature request to cover this case, too.  You'll notice that there is a separate filter for [repeated characters in body](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?reason=20) which only has a single hit on repeated exclamation marks.

Comment: @tripleee I think the point he's making is that it would only become common if repeated dots was banned.

Comment: Arguably, these posts should be flagged as "rude or abusive" on the grounds that they are a deliberate attempt to abuse the system. At the very least, they should be flagged as "very low quality". They need to be *deleted*, not just closed.

Comment: @tripleee once you have block the dots, they will be :)

Comment: @CodyGray I agree with you didn't though about that. I edited accordingly